# Eliminar elementos duplicados de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Leed la pregunta antes de marcarla como repetida, gracias.

Lo que necesito es que si en el array hay elementos duplicados, eliminarlos todos. El array es algo similar a este:

```
var array = [[1,2],
             [2,3], // repetido
             [3,4],
             [4,5],
             [2,3], // repetido
             [5,6],
             [6,7], // repetido
             [6,7], // repetido
             [7,8]]
```

por lo que quedaría asi:

```
var array = [[1,2],
            [3,4],
            [4,5],
            [5,6],
            [7,8]]
```

En el array pueden haber minimo 1000 valores, por lo que anidar un bucle for en otro, e ir comprobando valor por valor no es eficiente, se me cierra el navegador y el procesador se pone al 90%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La iteración del Array debe darse 1 sola vez, por cada elemento iterado debemos evaluar en un nuevo `array` si es que ya existe o no.

La explicación está en el código, las funciones que se utilizan son [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) para verificar que existe o no en el array,  y [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para eliminar los elementos del `array` duplicados.

```js
var array = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[2,3], [5,6],[6,7], [6,7], [7,8]]
let newArray = [];
array.forEach(elem=>{
  // verificamos si existe en el nuevo array , comparando su dos componentes
  // posición 0 y 1 , si no existe, añadimos el emenento al array
  if(!newArray.some(valor=> valor[0] === elem[0] && valor[1] === elem[1]))  
     newArray.push(elem);
  else {
 //caso contrario buscamos las coincidencias para eliminarlas
     newArray.forEach((valor,index)=> {
 //iteramos el array de no duplicados y eliminamos
 //los valores. con splice 
 if(valor[0]=== elem[0] && valor[1] === elem[1]) newArray.splice(index,1);
     });
  }
})
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto:

```js
var array = [[1,2],
             [2,3], // repetido
             [3,4],
             [4,5],
             [2,3], // repetido
             [5,6],
             [6,7], // repetido
             [6,7], // repetido
             [7,8]];
             
const eliminarRepetidos = (array) => {
    var unicos = [];
    var itemsEncontrados = {};
    for(var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(array[i]);
        if(itemsEncontrados[stringified]) { continue; }
        unicos.push(array[i]);
        itemsEncontrados[stringified] = true;
    }
    return unicos;
}

let arrayFiltrado = eliminarRepetidos(array);
console.log(arrayFiltrado);
```

La forma más sencilla en que podía pensar era **serializar** el valor del arreglo y almacenar si ya se había encontrado. [Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339709/10158153)